# limiting access to managers in the same role

Tags: security, role-hierarchy

what is the best way to limit managers in the same role to being able to only see the records they own and those of their subordinates. Thanks

Comment: pretty sure that's how it works by default with the role hierarchy

Comment: thanks Ralph. Just saw a similar thing in one of my SF books. Preciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use the role hierarchy.  For objects whose sharing settings include granting access via the role hierarchy it will work this way out of box.  Managers can see stuff their subordinates own, but not what other managers in their role would see.